# Number of columns returned by count() and explain query are different

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

[image: Explain on the same table]

Here, as you can see it shows more than a million rows in the table but in reality there are only 6 rows in it. There are 4 locks on this table by the ways.
And many a times I will just get an error saying "I/O error occurred while sending to the backend." this is due to the DB connection either timing out or closing, which is also because of the huge amount of data in the table.

[image: Count on the table's rows]

NOTE: Performing select/update/delete on this table can take between 30s-10m.

Comment: because explain without analyze shouws you estimations from statistics

Comment: Yes, actually explain with analyze gave me the exact number of rows. But how is the estimate so vague 1 million is nowhere close to 0?

Comment: Please do [not post screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - especially not of an execution plan. Post the plan as [**formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: If the plan shows completely wrong estimates (I can only guess because I can not really read the "text" in the screnshots) then you need to run `analyze table_name` to update the statistics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

explain without analyze shows you estimations from statistic - use `explain analyze` for exact plan and exact counts.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html

> ANALYZE
>
> Carry out the command and show actual run times and other
>   statistics. This parameter defaults to FALSE.

also https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html

Comment: Yes, actually explain with analyze gave me the exact number of rows. But how is the estimate for explain so vague 1 million is nowhere close to 0?

Comment: And can you help me figure out why deleting/updating/selecting took minutes when there were only 6 entries?

Comment: gather fresh stats (with vacuuming if you have autovacuum disabled) smth like `vacuum analyze user_patient_mapping`